# Embedded Docusign Signing URL - using document visibility to only show 1 document in the envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating an envelope via the Docusign Rest API. this envelope has 2 inline templates each have their own roles and do not share any tabs. I have a custom workflow that requires the user to fill in each document separately so i use the (/views/reciepients) endpoint to get a signing url.

The first signer sees the first (and only the first) document correctly, it is filled in and completed. Then i want to show the second document from the envelope in an iframe to a user. When i get the signing URL for the second recipient (signer) it also includes the first document all filled out. 
I have document visibility set up on the account.

I have read the documentation a few times and there is one confusing, under "Post Recipient View" there is a field "userName" which is not mentioned when creating the recipient or in the response from the recipient end point. I assume this is the "name" field.

to make it a bit easier to read i have put all the API requests into paste bin.

- Generate Envelope with 2 templates and 2 signers.

  - Request = http://pastebin.com/e98Dwaj8
- Get First signing URL  using /envelope/xxxx/views/recipient

  - Request = 
    `{
    "returnUrl": "http:\/\/local.example.com\/return.html",
    "authenticationMethod": "none",
    "email": "role1@example.com",
    "userName": "TestFirstName TestSurname",
    "clientUserId": "1"
    }`
- Get recipients for envelope after first signer has completed

  - Response = http://pastebin.com/9VmGsE3p
- Get second signing url (this shows both documents when visited)

  - Request = 
    `{
    "returnUrl": "http:\/\/local.example.com\/return.html",
    "authenticationMethod": "none",
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "userName": "TestFirstName TestSurname1",
    "clientUserId": "2"
    }`

Is there a way i can show the second signer only the second document?
Is it possible or will the completed document always show? does the /views/recipient url only hide documents in "draft" or "sent" and always shows "completed"?

*note: this is a follow up to [Docusign signing url - Showing document 1 of a composite template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950541/docusign-signing-url-showing-document-1-of-a-composite-template) but that question was answered and solved the original issue so i thought it best to open a new more specific question.*

Answer (score 2):

- In order for certain signers to only see certain documents, you will want to investigate the Document Visibility feature and settings. There is some starting documentation available at: https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-user-guide-advanced-sending-using-document-visibility-in-a-template
- In short, signers can only see documents in an envelope for which they have at least 1 tab assigned. This is honored during the signing ceremony as well as any view of the completed document.
- Regarding your last question, you should only be able to start a POST /recipient/view (signing ceremony) for an envelope which has been SENT. If you perform this action against an envelope which is completed it will start the signing session in a read only viewing mode (since the transaction is complete).

Comment: * Point 1: i believe i have document visibility set correctly. under preferences -> features i have "Must sign to view unless Sender Account" selected  * Point 2: i checked and each signer only has tabs on the document I want them to see. but the second signer still see's the first document. Is it just any tab or do they need to have a signature/initial tab on at least one document for it to work? * Point 3: The POST /recipient/view i am calling is for the second signer. the first signer is marked as complete but the second (as seen via GET /recipients) is in sent.

Comment: If a recipient has any DocuSign tab (e.g: date signed, checkbox, initial, signature, etc) on a page of a document, then they will have full visibility of that document. There very well may be other documents in the envelopes for which the recipient has no tags (but other recipients do), and therefore will not see those docs. I believe that if a document has ZERO DocuSign tabs, then everyone can see the doc.

Comment: There are definetly no shared tabs, will docusign always show completed documents?

Answer (score 0):

Is the 2nd signer a member on the sending account?  If so, they would be able to see all documents in the envelope based on "Must sign to view unless Sender Account".  This setting essentially means internal signers that have memberships on the same account as the Sender can see everything.