# DocuSign REST API v2 returning error ONESIGNALLSIGN_NOT_SATISFIED

Tags: docusignapi

I am having an issue with the DocuSign REST api (v2) attempting to create an envelope from a set of server templates (template stored with DS).  I connect with DS and they accept my JSON, however, I get an error message back:

**ONESIGNALLSIGN_NOT_SATISFIED** => **Freeform signing is not allowed for your account because it conflicts with other settings, please place signing tabs for each signer.**

I cannot figure out what the message is actually referring too.  I am in fact NOT including tabs for each signer in the JSON request, just the signer information and roleName.  This is very similar to the way we are generating envelopes with the SOAP api successfully (aka, we are not including tab information with the signer information for each document).

I based my JSON on this example:

https://github.com/Ergin008/DocuSign-REST-API-Webinar-April2013/blob/master/example3.json

I have done some extensive searching and reading on this problem, and have tried many different ways for structuring the request JSON per examples I have found, but it seems that this error is blocking any forward progress.  The only other place I could find a reference to another person struggling with this error was here:

[Docusign signing url - Showing document 1 of a composite template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950541/docusign-signing-url-showing-document-1-of-a-composite-template)

I tried to use some of that information to work out the kink to no avail.  I am not completely sure what they are referencing with "Document Visability" etc...  This could be my problem...

Any help that could be provided is greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

JSON:

```
{
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "Testing DocuSign REST",
    "emailBlurb": "",
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": 1,
                    "templateId": "9F712D11-2524-433F-98F0-D3ADCC041B42"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": 1,
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "recipientId": "28214",
                                "clientUserId": "28214",
                                "email": “test1@yahoo.com",
                                "name": "COLBY",
                                "roleName": "BORROWER1",
                                "requireIDLookup": false
                            },
                            {
                                "recipientId": "13020",
                                "clientUserId": "13020",
                                "email": “test2@YAHOO.COM",
                                "name": “CHEESE”,
                                "roleName": "BORROWER3",
                                "requireIDLookup": false
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "customFields": {
                        "textCustomFields": [
                            {
                                "name": "PDF_CLIENT",
                                "value": "108"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": 2,
                    "templateId": "06E28E05-FF6F-4CD0-962A-7EBF3EE78BC5"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": 2,
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "recipientId": "28214",
                                "clientUserId": "28214",
                                "email": “test1@yahoo.com",
                                "name": "COLBY",
                                "roleName": "BORROWER1",
                                "requireIDLookup": false
                            },
                            {
                                "recipientId": "13020",
                                "clientUserId": "13020",
                                "email": “test2@YAHOO.COM",
                                "name": “CHEESE”,
                                "roleName": "BORROWER3",
                                "requireIDLookup": false
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "customFields": {
                        "textCustomFields": [
                            {
                                "name": "PDF_CLIENT",
                                "value": "108"
                            }                        
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": 3,
                    "templateId": "B702BFAD-DE2C-411E-A7EF-EA1E12805341"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": 3,
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "recipientId": "28214",
                                "clientUserId": "28214",
                                "email": “test1@yahoo.com",
                                "name": "COLBY",
                                "roleName": "BORROWER1",
                                "requireIDLookup": false
                            },
                            {
                                "recipientId": "13020",
                                "clientUserId": "13020",
                                "email": “test2@YAHOO.COM",
                                "name": “CHEESE”,
                                "roleName": "BORROWER3",
                                "requireIDLookup": false
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "customFields": {
                        "textCustomFields": [
                            {
                                "name": "PDF_CLIENT",
                                "value": "108"
                            }                        
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "eventNotification": {
        "url": “oureventhandlingprogramurl”,
        "loggingEnabled": true,
        "envelopeEvents": [
            {
                "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Sent",
                "includeDocuments": false
            },
            {
                "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Delivered",
                "includeDocuments": false
            },
            {
                "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed",
                "includeDocuments": false
            },
            {
                "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Declined",
                "includeDocuments": false
            },
            {
                "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Voided",
                "includeDocuments": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And the response

```
{
    "errorCode": "ONESIGNALLSIGN_NOT_SATISFIED",
    "message": "Freeform signing is not allowed for your account because it conflicts with other settings, please place signing tabs for each signer."
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research, we found the issue in the DocuSign admin panel settings.

**"Document Visibility"** is one of the settings (its a dropdown) and setting it to "off" got us past the issue.

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had two signers for a template but one of the signers didnt have any associated data tabs. After assigning data tabs to both signers, that fixed the above issue for us, and we were able to leave "Document Visibility" turned on.